# Orleans: "Running in a Stand Alone Silo" example does not run

Tags: orleans

I have just started to get myself familiar with Orleans for a project. I have some questions regarding that. I am currently using the Step by Step Tutorial. Unfortunately when I try to run the example with "Running in a Stand-Alone Silo" in my laptop, the Grains collection fails with lots of exceptions. I am not sure how to troubleshoot that?

The document mentions "OrleansHost.exe is a ready-made host executable intended for running Orleans code on Windows Server (Azure has a different host)". I am not sure what this means? Is this the reason why it does not work on my laptop which has Windows 10 running?

Comment: What are the exceptions?

Comment: Where can I find the logs? The command line pops up and then vanishes.

Comment: Have you tried running it with Ctrl+F5 instead of just F5? That usually works.

Comment: There should be a log file generated alongside the silo executable. If it is not there, check the `<Tracing DefaultTraceLevel="Info" TraceToConsole="true" TraceToFile="{0}-{1}.log" >` element in your config.

Comment: @svick: I tried using Ctrl + F5. The OrleansHost terminal comes up and vanished after getting an exception.

Comment: @ReubenBond: I checked the logs in path HelloWorld/bin/Debug. There are two types of log, one prefixed as client and other prefixed with my computer's host name. I assume the client is the correct log. It has this error "WARNING 100178 Messaging.GatewayConnection/GatewayClientSender_gwy.tcp://127.0.0.1:40000/0 127.0.0.1:0] Unable to connect to gateway at address gwy.tcp://127.0.0.1:40000/0 on trial 0."

Comment: @MainakGhosh could you paste the entire logs into a gist/pastebin? Is your silo fully started when you start your client?

Comment: @ReubenBond: I have pasted a server and a client log. I am not sure they are from the same run though http://pastebin.com/ZQdy0cNZ

Answer (score 0):

From your logs, it looks like you're still connecting to the gateway by port 4000, the default one. Have you tried specifying your client to use the same port as your server? The example uses port 3000:

```
var config = Orleans.Runtime.Configuration.ClientConfiguration.LocalhostSilo(30000);
```